# bitwise OR on short and long (java)

Tags: java, casting, bit-manipulation

The following code calculates the parity of number.

The question is what happens in the line **count^=(number&1)**. The bitwise AND operation will result in a long. The a bitwise OR is performed between a short (count) and a long (number&1), which should result in a long. **Why can the result still be saved in a short valiable (count)?**

```
long number=17;

public short parityCalc() {
    short count=0;

    for(int c=0;c<64;c++){
        count^=(number&1);
        number>>>=1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: The question had nothing to do with the compound assignment operator. I changed the question now so that the compound assignment operator is left out.

Comment: Your new code  doesn't compile. It only compiled because of the compound assignment operator. Read the duplicate.

Comment: what is "number>>>=1;" ?

Comment: To be clear, I'm referring to the compound `^=` operator in the first revision of your question.

Comment: Thanks, Sotirios! It was indeed a duplicate. It turns out that the compound assignment operator is also performing a cast.